# Lack of fit test in multiple regression

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression

Suppose I have this model
$$Y=B_0+B_1X_1+B_2X_2$$
and these observations

```
Y  <- c(64, 73, 61, 76, 72, 80, 71, 83, 83, 89, 86, 93, 88, 95, 94, 100)
X1 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10)
X2 <- c(2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4)
```

I know how to calculate SSLF (1) and SSPE (2) in R, but I want to know how to do it at hand
$$SSLF=SSE-SSPE$$
where
$$SSE=\sum(Y_i-\hat{Y_i})^2$$
[image]

setting up the table this way is easy to calculate the sum of squares of pure error, but there is an easier way to do this?

(1) **SSLF:** sum of squares of lack of fit

(2) **SSPE:** sum of squares of pure error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give you a hint. The SSPE is made up of squared deviations from the means at each $X$ level. Let's denote the number of $X$ levels by $c$, then

$$SSPE=\sum_j^c \sum_{i}^{n_j} \left(Y_{ij} - \bar{Y_j} \right)^2$$.

Simply put, for a replicate, i.e. an identical $X$ value, you compute the mean of the the corresponding $Y$s and sum the squared deviations from it. It is easy to see that any $X$ level with no replications makes no contribution to SSPE because the mean is just that one observation!

Hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: I need to do $$(64-mean(64+61))^2+\dots+(100-mean(95+100))^2$$ or is there another way? It's hard to do this by hand with several variables

Comment: @PRAGAKHAM I am sorry I don't know any other way but depending on your software, perhaps you can program a loop?

Comment: Actually I was trying to learn the best way to do this by hand, but thanks.

Comment: @PRAGAKHAM I doubt there is a shortcut so if you would like to do it by hand, at least use a calculator!

Answer (score 1):

This might sound a little redundant, but the formula that @JohnK provides is probably as simple as you can get.  However, if there are an equal number $n_j=n$ of observations at each level $c$, as in the case in your original post, you can simply the formula he has provided a bit further by expanding the terms inside the parentheses to obtain:

$SSPE$=$\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{ij}^2-n\sum_{j=1}^c\bar{Y_j}^2$.

Using this formula, with $c=8$ and $n_j=n=2$, you get:

$SSPE$=$108896-(2)(54419.5)=57$.

This might be easier for hand computation.  If the only levels that have unequal numbers of observations have only a single observation, then you can still carry out this formula by simply deleting those observations from the computation.  But I think the original formula presented is easier for grasping the concept of $SSPE$.  As @JohnK indicated, it's essentially the sum of the deviations of each measurement around the mean of all the other measurements at that same level.  When there is only a single measurement at that level, the measurement is the same as the mean, so the contribution of that measurement is zero and the level can be "disregarded."